# How to handle deprecation of do...end in Elixir/Phoenix after v0.9.0?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was using Phoenix v0.9.0 until today. To get a bug fix I switched to the master branch, but now this warning appears while running `mix compile`:

```
warning: using do...end in views is deprecated, please use the new YourApp.Web definitions
    web/view.ex:6: Youli.View (module)
```

I'd like to do that. How can I get started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to draft some upgrade guides this weekend when 0.10 is released that will help here, but for now this should get you up and running:

1) Add a `MyApp.Web` file to `web/`. Model it after here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/template/web/web.ex

2) Migrate your `web/view.ex` `using` block to the new `web/web.ex` block. Delete. `web/view.ex`.

2) Update all your views like here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/template/web/views/page_view.ex#L2

3) Update all your controllers like here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/template/web/controllers/page_controller.ex#L2

Hope that helps!

Comment: Got it. The <%= application_module %> tag has to be replaced with the actual application module name everywhere. I'm not sure how to migrate the using block though.

Comment: Everything you had in your `using` block just goes here: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/template/web/web.ex#L17-L23

Comment: All right, that's a no-op for my project. Now there's another compile error on endpoint.ex about :pubsub but it doesn't seem to be related.